# Unable to set Audio Jack on Pi Zero W

Tags: audio, pi-zero-w

I'm trying to get PWM audio to work on my Pi Zero W. I've followed [these directions](https://shallowsky.com/blog/hardware/pi-zero-audio.html), specifically adding the `dtoverlay` part to `/boot/config.txt`. The output of `gpio readall`, as suggested in this related [Adafruit article](https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-basic-audio-ouput-to-raspberry-pi-zero/pi-zero-pwm-audio), looks just as it should - pin 13 on ALT0 and 18 on ALT5.

This is where I get stuck. The Adafruit article directs me to activate the headphone jack in `raspi-config`, but I seem to be on a much different version of the tool (understandable, since all these articles are rather old by now). There is indeed a menu option to select audio outputs, but it only gives me the HDMI option, nothing else.

How do I convince my Pi to use the GPIO pins for PWM audio output, instead of the HDMI port?

Comment: 2017 article and a 2015 adafruit article - no surprise they don't help - also, take a close look at your raspberry pi 0 ... does it have a headphone jack? (hint: no, it does not)

Comment: I'm well aware it doesn't have a headphone jack. That's the whole point of these articles. I'm also not surprised that they might be outdated, but evidently there *was* a way to do this, and I'm wondering how (or if at all) that translates to today's versions.